# Characters are not displayed correctly by using FiraMono font (dvips -> ps2pdf)

Tags: fonts, minted

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{default}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[]{python}
with open('data/anna-karenina.txt', encoding='koi8-r') as stream:
    # Use stream.readline() to retrieve the next line from a file,
    # in this case the 1st one:
    line = stream.readline()

print(line)
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[]{text}
Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая несчастливая семья
несчастлива по-своему.
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

**Ouput**

[image]

**But the output should be as**

[image]

Note that I'm using `Windows, MikTeX 2.9` and `LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf`
Please suggest what went wrong in my tags...

Comment: May I suggest using a different LaTeX engine like LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? You don't have to deal with all these encoding hassles then (if you stay within UTF-8). They support OpenType fonts (ps and type1 based), so Fira should 'just work'.

Comment: @larkey Thanks for your tips, I already noticed that `XeLaTeX` works fine, but I forced to use the `dvips` and PS2PDF` format only....That's the issue....Any how, thanks....

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549978/4427), Fira Mono has no support for the T2A encoding.

You can use DejaVu Sans Mono that has support for Cyrillic. Anyway, with `pdflatex` you can't (easily) mix Cyrillic and Latin if the default encoding is T1. Thus I provided a `t2a` environment for the purpose. Mixing *is* possible if the current encoding is T2A.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{default}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}

\newenvironment{t2a}
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[]{python}
with open('data/anna-karenina.txt', encoding='koi8-r') as stream:
    # Use stream.readline() to retrieve the next line from a file,
    # in this case the 1st one:
    line = stream.readline()

print(line)
\end{minted}

\begin{t2a}
\begin{minted}[]{text}
Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая несчастливая семья
несчастлива по-своему.
\end{minted}
\end{t2a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to stick to Fira Mono for Latin, you can still do it.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{default}
\usepackage{FiraMono}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\ttdefault}{DejaVuSansMono-TLF}

\newenvironment{t2a}
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{t2a}
\begin{minted}[]{python}
with open('data/anna-karenina.txt', encoding='koi8-r') as stream:
    # Use stream.readline() to retrieve the next line from a file,
    # in this case the 1st one:
    line = stream.readline()

print(line)
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[]{text}
Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая несчастливая семья
несчастлива по-своему.
\end{minted}
\end{t2a}

\end{document}
```

In this case, however, you should not mix Latin and Cyrillic in the same `minted` environment.

[image]

Comment: Sir, I got this error `Undefined control sequence.
 \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution
                                  {T2A}{\ttdefault}{DejaVuSansMono-TLF}` if I use your second suggestion....Please advise...

Comment: Sir, If I follow your first suggestion, then the errors `Missing character: There is no ¸ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!
Missing character: There is no ‹ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!
Missing character: There is no ¸ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!
Missing character: There is no ¸ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!
Missing character: There is no ¸ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!
Missing character: There is no ¸ in font DejaVuSansMono-tlf-t2a!` are coming, please advise what wrong I did. I used the command `latex -shell-escape filename.tex` and `yap filename.dvi` to view the output...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Please, no “sir”. You need to update your TeX system. What TeX distribution are you running? And do you really need DVI files and not PDF?

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` solved the issue....Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 5):

You need to load T2A encoding and for the cyrillic commands to switch to it. But the type1 version of Fira has no support for T2A so it falls back to cmr:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/FiraMono-TOsF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead
```

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{default}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\CYRV}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrs}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyre}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrch}{T2A}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyra}{T2A}
% and so on...
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[]{text}
Все сча
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion....