# code input with linenumbers

Tags: input, external-files, line-numbering, python

I write a thesis and want to have my code/textfile in the appendix.
I dont want to copy the code, I only want to write the path of my file into tex.

I already tried `\verbatiminput{main.py}` and `\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{main.py}` but I need to have the line numbered.

## Needed features

- numbering lines
- load from textfile (not copying)

## Nice to have features

These features would be nice, but I can manage to work around.

- use tab as indent
- break line, if line is to long

## Not necessary at all, but very nice to have

Is there a simple way to highlight python syntax?

---

### Edit

As [MadyYuvi sugest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553318/173231), I tried `\lstinputlisting`. In one file I got an umalut (ä), so it failed to compile.
`! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "A4.`
[In a german forum](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?t=4487) I found an suggestion to use `\usepackage{listingsutf8}` but it does not help.

### Edit

#### minimal working example (MWE)

document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,language=Python,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true,breakindent=12pt,]{main.py}

\end{document}
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('I have got umlauts like ä,ö,ü in my code.')
```

Comment: try with `minted.sty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps..,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,language=Python,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true,breakindent=12pt,]{test.py}

\end{document}
```

**Updation**

If you have any special characters in programming code, then try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,language=Python,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true,breakindent=12pt]{test.py}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Compile this file "XeLaTeX", this is because of font issues...

Also, refer this, `Ulrike` and `egreg` gave their wonderful suggestion,  [Characters are not displayed correctly by using FiraMono font (dvips -> ps2pdf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549973/characters-are-not-displayed-correctly-by-using-firamono-font-dvips-ps2pdf?noredirect=1#comment1389430_549973)

Comment: That works for some files without umlauts in it. Do you know how to change it for umlauts?

Comment: Where does the `umlauts` come? Inside `program code`??

Comment: Yes I got some in my programcode.

Comment: Can you post a `MWE` on your code for better understanding ?....

Comment: I edited my question with the MWE based on your answer and a python file. Does this help you to understand my problem?

Comment: This is related with font issue, refer the updated suggestion....